# How to tell to qemu to copy the ram into a file

Tags: qemu, osdev

I am making an OS and I am debugging it using the Qemu. I want a way to read some big blocks of the ram at the end of some instructions. How to do that? Can say to Qemu to copy the ram into a file? If not what I can do?

Comment: You can do this by using the QEMU monitor. You can set a break point in QEMU let the program run until where you want to dump memory. Click on the QEMU window your program is running in and switch to the monitor by using Alt-2 (or may be control-alt-2). You should get a command line. You can use the command `pmemsave` to dump physical memory with something like `pmemsave 0x100000 4096 outfile.mem` which would dump 4096 bytes starting at 0x100000 and dump it to file `outfile.mem`. You can dump virtual memory with `memsave` instead of `pmemsave` .

Comment: I redid my comment. it mistakenly said `f2` where it was suppose to be `2` . The monitor key sequence is either control-alt-2 or alt-2

Answer (score 5):

qmp or hmp command `dump-guest-memory`.