# A VM nested inside another VM. Is there any way to retrieve the kernel of nested VM while in top level VM?

Tags: linux, security, process, linux-kernel

Alright, So I have a VM running inside another VM. I'll call the first, top level VM level 1, and the nested VM level 2.

My goal is to read the memory of the nested VM (level 2) while inside the level 1 VM.

Background information of the VMs. They are both Linux based, 32-bit OS. They can both be Linux V4.4.14. (I have different set-ups).

What I know...
The memory of the Linux OS Virtual based, and my target (the kernel) lyes within the memory addresses 0xc0000000 to 0xffffffff for a 32-bit Linux OS. I have successfully read the kernel memory and gotten the information I want from the level 1 VM.

Theory's tried so far to retrieve the level 2 VM kernel from the level 1 VM...
Me and my professor believed because the level 2 VM was running like any other program in the level 1 VM that we would be about to simple read the memory from addresses 0x00000000 to 0xc0000000, and find the same structure of data from the level 1 VM's kernel.

What has been tried thus far...
I have scanned the memory from 0x00000000 to 0xc0000000, targeting specific information that I know is within the kernel of the level 2 VM. My results were empty, nil. I couldn't find any exact matches for what I was looking for.

Next approach...
Me and my professor believe the data for the level 2 VM is in it's own space that we cannot access with the current functions of our program.

What we need to know...
Where is the level 2 kernel in the level 1 memory? How does this nested VM inside a VM work? I hope someone out there can help, or I might be screwed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you nest the virtual machines?

Comment: "How does this nested VM inside a VM work?" - Nested VM works inside outer VM in the **same way** as VM works inside "normal" OS (host). So your question seems to be effectively "How to retrieve the VM Linux kernel from the host".

Comment: But, what do you mean by "retrieve the kernel"? The Linux kernel consist from many  memory segments (allocated when requested). All these segments are inside (0x00000000, 0xc0000000) range, but it could be a gap between segments with unused memory. You may dump entire (0x00000000, 0xc0000000) range, so all segments represented the kernel will be dumped too. But what do you want to with that dump? Your question is not clear.

Comment: How are you running the inner ("level 2") virtual machine? Is it using QEMU? Or KVM? Parallels? Something else? This makes a huge difference to just how the VM's memory is mapped. Also, as Tsyvarev asked, please be more specific as to what exactly you're trying to do.
Note that due to paging etc. it is possible that some of the level-2-VM's memory will not be mapped at all but will reside on disk. Depending on how you run the VM, there may be tools that do what you want.

Comment: Me and my professor have a program that retrieves the process list from the linux kernel, like using command "ps" in shell, in order to compare the process list stored in the kernel to the process list printed out with "ps" command. Attackers can hide processes that show with the "ps" command, but not hide the raw process info stored in the kernel.

Comment: I mean the entire "dump" of the kernel from level 2 while operating in level 1. In other words, retrieve the entire kernel of level 2 VM without actually going into it like a normal user. I'm looking for a way to retrieve it via a class or at least understand how it is stored.

Comment: We are using QEMU.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397607/how-to-tell-to-qemu-to-copy-the-ram-into-a-file)?